# createDirectoryAtPath:attributes: alternative

Tags: iphone, directory, nsfilemanager

[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:attributes:] gives me a warning that it is depreciated.

What is the alternative? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`

**P.S.**

> **createIntermediates** If YES, then the
>   method will also create any necessary
>   intermediate directories; if NO, then
>   the method fails if any parent of the
>   directory to be created does not
>   exist. In addition, if you pass NO for
>   this parameter, the directory must not
>   exist at the time this call is made.

Comment: what would you pass to `withIntermediateDirectories` can you pass nil? What does it do?

Comment: ah i see... so if you have a path to the folder you want to create like: *Documents/A/Directory/In/Here* and you set `withIntermediateDirectories` to NO then it will fail if any of the directories *A*,*Directory* and *In* don't exist. If YES then it will create them if they don't exist? Brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: Or [the URL-based alternative, `createDirectoryatURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:). Apple's been increasingly nudging developers toward using URLs instead of strings to refer to things in the file-system.