# Create folder/directory in Objective-C/cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, directory

I have this code for creating a folder/directory in Objective-C/cocoa.

```
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directory isDirectory:&isDir])
        if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:directory attributes:nil])
            NSLog(@"Error: Create folder failed %@", directory);
```

It works fine, but I got `creatDirectoryAtPath:attributes is deprecated` warning message.
What's the newest way of making a directory builder in Cocoa/Objective-c?

### SOLVED

```
BOOL isDir;
NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directory isDirectory:&isDir])
    if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:directory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL])
        NSLog(@"Error: Create folder failed %@", directory);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [createDirectoryAtPath:attributes: alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880786/createdirectoryatpathattributes-alternative)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Found in the documentation:

[`-[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW5)

Answer (score 20):

Your solution is correct, though Apple includes an important note within `NSFileManager.h`:

```
/* The following methods are of limited utility. Attempting to predicate behavior 
based on the current state of the filesystem or a particular file on the 
filesystem is encouraging odd behavior in the face of filesystem race conditions. 
It's far better to attempt an operation (like loading a file or creating a 
directory) and handle the error gracefully than it is to try to figure out ahead 
of time whether the operation will succeed. */

- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path;
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory;
- (BOOL)isReadableFileAtPath:(NSString *)path;
- (BOOL)isWritableFileAtPath:(NSString *)path;
- (BOOL)isExecutableFileAtPath:(NSString *)path;
- (BOOL)isDeletableFileAtPath:(NSString *)path;
```

Essentially, if multiple threads/processes are modifying the file system simultaneously the state could change in between calling `fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:` and calling `createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:`, so it is superfluous and possibly dangerous to call `fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:` in this context.

For your needs and within the limited scope of your question it likely would not be a problem, but the following solution is both simpler and offers less of a chance of future issues arising:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:directory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]) {
     // An error has occurred, do something to handle it
     NSLog(@"Failed to create directory \"%@\". Error: %@", directory, error);
}
```

Also note from [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW5):

> **Return Value**
>
> YES if the directory was created, YES if createIntermediates is set
>   and the directory already exists), or NO if an error occurred.

So, setting `createIntermediates` to `YES`, which you already do, is a de facto check of whether the directory already exists.

Comment: This answer should be marked as accepted as it contains a lot more details and IS the right answer : You don't have to use fileExistsAtPath if you have "withIntermediateDirectories:YES"

Comment: This is indeed the best answer. Just for clarity, if you do not want to have the directory overwritten, set withIntermediateDirectories:NO. This will be documented in the error.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for some clarification on the subject.

Comment: Provides a _de facto check of whether the directory already exists_ when `withIntermediateDirectories` is set to `true` in Swift. (`createDirectory(at: someUrl, withIntermediateDirectories: true`)

Answer (score 3):

Thought I'd add to this and mention some more from the documentation about using the  +defaultManager method:

*In iOS and Mac OS X v 10.5 and later you should consider using [[NSFileManager alloc] init] rather than the singleton method defaultManager. Instances of NSFileManager are considered thread-safe when created using [[NSFileManager alloc] init].*

Comment: It's safe to use the `defaultManager`. "The methods of the shared NSFileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely. However, if you use a delegate to receive notifications about the status of move, copy, remove, and link operations, you should create a unique instance of the file manager object, assign your delegate to that object, and use that file manager to initiate your operations."

Answer (score 3):

You may prefer to work with the `NSFileManager` method:

[`createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtURL%3awithIntermediateDirectories%3aattributes%3aerror%3a)

It works with URL's instead of path strings.