# Adding an open In option to the share sheet in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios12

I am familiar with the share functionality on IOS. I share items in my app using

```
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
```

My question is how do I add an open with option to the share sheet of my app ?

Comment: The list of app is dependent on what items you pass to the activity controller.

Comment: I am passing an image to the activity controller , still i dont see a copyTo feature. Apparently some popular apps like imgure dont even have that. Is there anything special that google drive does that i am not aware of ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Open in…" options are made available based on the content that's being opened and the document types supported by the device's installed apps. It's not something you can alter from your app.

On the other hand, if the apps that you want to appear in your app's "Open in" list are other apps you have control over, then you can add `CFBundleDocumentTypes` keys to those apps' info.plists. This tells iOS that the apps can open certain types of files. You specify supported filetypes using UTIs like `public.jpeg` and so on, and when a user tries to open one of those file types from a UIActivityViewController, ios will include the supporting applications in the options.

Here's a good discussion of that: [How do I get my application to show up in the Open in... menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html)

And here's a discussion on UTIs: [Uniform Type Identifier Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html)

So, for example, if one of your apps supported opening jpeg images and any text file, you would add this to the info.plist:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Images</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.jpeg</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>text</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.plain-text</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

But, again, if you're trying to manipulate the apps that are shown as "Open in" options from the app displaying the activity controller, you can't. You can only make your own apps advertise that they support certain document types, and from that iOS builds up its "Open in" options.

Answer (score 0):

In This Post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55350564/10861969

- Above post just show copy into  without adding below line.
- for showing "**copy into**" to "**open in**"

  `Supports opening documents in place : YES`

[image]

**References**:-

- [Adding an open In option to the share sheet in ObjectiveC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270708/adding-an-open-in-option-to-the-share-sheet-in-objectivec)
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html
- [Swift - Open file imported to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440863/swift-open-file-imported-to-app)
- https://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/01/open-in-all-files/
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html
- https://bignerdranch.com/blog/working-with-the-files-app-in-ios-11/
- [Creating my own file extension based on plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827558/creating-my-own-file-extension-based-on-plist)