# Creating a directory - what replaces createDirectoryAtPath?

Tags: cocoa, deprecated, file-manager

I have the following line of code in my program which I took from the Forth edition of Stephen G. Kochan's book "Programming in Objective-C:

```
[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:DATABASE_DIRECTORY attributes:nil];
```

Note: "fileManager" is my fm variable, and DATABASE_DIRECTORY is a #define of my path.

While it works perfectly fine (I'm running OSX 10.6.8), every time I compile I am reminded that:

```
"createDirectoryAtPath:attributes:" is deprecated
```

I've looked over the reference document for the file manager, and it is a bit overwhelming for a newbie to Cocoa Programming.  Regardless, that particular method is no longer listed in the only filemanager reference docs I could find (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html)  It is not even listed as "deprecated".  It's just not there at all.

Clearly, it still works, but obviously the idea is to utilize a different and more modern way of creating a directory (I noticed that the filemanager reference is a Carbon vs. Cocoa reference.  I have not tried running this on Lion yet to see if it still works.)

Is there a direct replacement for this deprecated method?

If not, is Apple trying to do away with path names and instead switch over to Unicode entirely? (Forgive me if I'm a bit confused on this issue and terminology... I haven't written code since the late 80's...)  I have never really used Unicode for anything in the past so I wouldn't know where to begin.

If anyone can recommend a good *current* primer on Unicode and/or programming code to read/write files in Cocoa, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [createDirectoryAtPath:attributes: alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880786/createdirectoryatpathattributes-alternative)

Comment: Unicode is a character set. Paths are written using those characters. It doesn't make sense to switch from a certain kind of text to the characters that that text is written in. As for the File Manager docs you linked to, that's the Core Services File Manager, not NSFileManager; NSFileManager, as part of Cocoa, is documented in the Cocoa documentation. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Apple is doing is moving away from paths toward URLs -- I don't know if they will go all the way, but they do seem to be depreciating quite a few of the path methods in favor of URL ones.  The replacement for createDirectoryAtPath:attributes: is createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:

I'm not sure why you couldn't find that in the docs, if you search for createDirectoryAtPath:attributes: it takes you to the depreciated methods and in that reference it points you to the replacement.

Comment: I'll do some research into converting it over to a URL then.  Thanks!